# Abrir ventana de explorador de Archivos desde HTML

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, windows

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un requerimiento que consta de lo siguiente:

1. Los usuarios, necesitan acceso a una interfaz en la cual, mediante links puedan abrir diferentes carpetas del **Explorador de Archivos de Windows**.
2. Una vez que abierta la interfaz del **Explorador de Archivos de Windows**, los usuarios abrirán y navegarán en diferentes carpetas para abrir diferentes archivos.

*Cabe aclarar, que la acción de abriri los archivos no será mediante el sisteman, para ello el abrir el explorador de archivos, y que la funcionalidad de windows haga el resto.*

He estado buscando una posible solución a este requerimiento, pero no he encontrado una forma de hacerlo.
En tanto a HTML, conozco que el input tipo file `<input type="file">` puede abrir una venta de explorador de archivos, pero, dicho input solo sirve para la sección de archivos.

Desconozco si existe alguna API o si hay alguna forma de solucionar este requerimiento, talvez utilizar otro enfoque.

De igual manera, tengo montada la aplicación en Java (Spring, MVC) y el front son JSP's (basado en HTML)

Comment: Por seguridad, los navegadores no permiten abrir otros programas ni tener acceso al sistema de archivos. Tal vez podrías crear un protocolo personalizado como se explica en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56775043/2412893) (en inglés), pero debes hacerlo en cada equipo donde deseas que funcione.

Comment: Lo revisaré,
por suerte el requerimiento aplica solo a 3 usuarios, y los equipos son fijos,

Muchas gracias!